# How to import data-binding in Android app (Java)?

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

I had imported data-binding package in another application but, now I am trying to copy paste the same file in another project its showing an error!

I have enabled dataBinding in android in build.gradle (app level) as:

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

activity_maps.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/google_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

</androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
```

I know that we need to convert layout in .xml file as dataBinding type  but, I had used the same code (only package was different).

MapsActivity.java:

```java
package com.Inchargenext.loginactivity;

import com.Inchargenext.loginactivity.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private ActivityMapsBinding binding;
}
```

Here I can't import the databing or create ActivityMapsBinding object as import is necessary.

Comment: Avoid copy-pasting files from one project to another. Try to reproduce what you did in one project by typing it, or maybe copy-paste some code. I've never worked with data-binding with Java, only with Kotlin, but for me it looks that everything is okay

Comment: You need to use <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"> tag on the top hierarchy of your xml file In order to autogenrate binding files.
then you can manually use
  ActivityMapsBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_maps)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to succefully import the databing file after editing the build.gradle's android's buildFeatures as:

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
    viewBinding = true
}
```

Also, make sure above, and below code is written in app level build.gradle:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use databinding in your Java (or Kotlin) classes, you have to change your XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/google_map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

</layout>
```

Then, you will be able to do `private ActivityMapsBinding binding;`
And import that binding variable.

Also, check this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-data-binding-basics?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#0), because if you understand how it does work will help you in the future.